# Transoformar Linhas em Colunas em SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Acessei um banco de dados e fiz o seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT P.NomeRazaoSocial,
       DT.Nome [Taxa],
       D.AnoReferencia,
       GPDD.ValorDevido

FROM Cadastro.Pessoas AS P
    JOIN Financeiro.Debitos AS D
        ON D.IdPessoa = P.IdPessoa
    JOIN Financeiro.DebitosTipos AS DT
        ON DT.IdDebitoTipo = D.IdDebitoTipo
    JOIN Financeiro.GeracoesPosicoesDividasDebitos AS GPDD
        ON GPDD.IdDebito = D.IdDebito
WHERE P.NomeRazaoSocial = 'LUCAS';
```

Os resultados saíram da seguinte maneira :

| Nome | Taxa | AnoReferencia | ValorDevido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lucas | Anuidade | 2018 | 500 |
| :---- | :-------: | :------------: | :-----------: |
| Lucas | Anuidade | 2019 | 600 |
| :---- | :-------: | :------------: | :-----------: |
| Lucas | Anuidade | 2020 | 700 |
| :---- | :-------: | :------------: | :-----------: |
| Lucas | Anuidade | 2021 | 800 |

Porém eu gostaria que fosse apresentado as colunas de TAXA, ANOREFERENCIA E VALORDEVIDO na mesma linha mas em cédulas separadas como exemplo :

```
| NOME | Taxa 1 | AnoReferencia 1 | ValorDevido1 | Taxa 2 | AnoReferencia 2 | ValorDevido 3 |
```

E assim por diante. Creio que tenha que usar Pivot mas não entendo muito sobre e gostaria de ajuda.

Comment: exato, *pivot* vai resolver esse problema, já fez uma [pesquisa por pivot](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot) aqui no site?

Comment: Até onde saiba mysql não tem "pivot" nativo a solução é usar. CASE por exemplo ... https://linuxhint.com/mysql_pivot/